# Duct tape + spackle to fix hole under window ledge?

Tags: hole-repair, spackling-paste, duct-tape

In one of the bedrooms in my apartment under the window, part of the bottom of the ledge has collapsed. Not sure what caused it. Not sure what it is made of either, probably concrete or something similar. At its widest the hole is about 3 cm, which is a little too wide to fill with just spackle. I was wondering if I could patch the hole with duct tape and then add the spackle over it so it has something to adhere to?

Comment: Shouldn't WD-40 also come into play somehow?

Comment: @Harper I feel I should know what that is but I don’t :-) someone at the hardware store told me I didn’t need to add primer or anything like that but I’m not sure.

Comment: WD-40 is a not particularly good but very well-marketed oil in a spray can.  It is low comedy in handyman circles that a quick fix for ANY problem can be accomplished with enough duct tape and WD-40!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Use proper drywall tape of either the paper or fiberglass varieties. Both are cheap and won't leave you with a gooey, hollow, fragile mess. I also recommend proper joint compound. Spackle is very light and soft and not suitable for filling large depressions. If you're dealing with concrete or regular moisture, consider a setting-type compound for toughness. (It comes as a dry powder and requires water.)

1. Prefill the hole with joint compound using a small taping knife and allow it to dry completely. Deep fills can take a day or more to stop shrinking and look completely white. A fan helps.
2. Skim again to wet the entire area with compound.
3. Overlay a patch of tape and press it in lightly with the knife.
4. Either now or after the skim coat dries, skim again to overcoat the tape. Let this dry and repeat as necessary, seeking to apply the thinnest and smoothest coat that seems to do the job. There's very little sanding with a good taping job.
5. Sand, prime/seal, paint. Be proud that you aren't a hack doing pretend repairs.